# creatingand triggering the custom ovject webhoks in marketo

Tags: marketo

How do we create a **custom object webhook in marketo** and how do we trigger it?

Is there any reference guide for this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Marketo Webhooks cannot pull parameters from Custom Objects and neither can they return data into Custom Objects, assuming that you want to do one of those 2 things. You probably want to use the Marketo REST API.